# Jersey Grizzly HTTP Server shutdown inside container docker

Tags: java, docker, jersey, docker-compose, grizzly

I am trying to execute a Grizzly HTTP Server inside a container.

My problem is that when I am running the container (using docker-compose) the container shuts down after a few seconds.

Here is my server **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM alpine:3.5

MAINTAINER Maybe One <maybe@maybe.com>

# Java Version and other ENV
ENV JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR=8 \
    JAVA_VERSION_MINOR=102 \
    JAVA_VERSION_BUILD=14 \
    JAVA_PACKAGE=jdk \
    JAVA_JCE=standard \
    JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk \
    PATH=${PATH}:/opt/jdk/bin \
    GLIBC_VERSION=2.23-r3 \
    LANG=C.UTF-8

RUN apk upgrade --update && \
    apk add --update libstdc++ curl ca-certificates bash && \
    for pkg in glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION} glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION} glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VERSION}; do curl -sSL https://github.com/andyshinn/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/${pkg}.apk -o /tmp/${pkg}.apk; done && \
    apk add --allow-untrusted /tmp/*.apk && \
    rm -v /tmp/*.apk && \
    ( /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef --force --inputfile POSIX --charmap UTF-8 C.UTF-8 || true ) && \
    echo "export LANG=C.UTF-8" > /etc/profile.d/locale.sh && \
    /usr/glibc-compat/sbin/ldconfig /lib /usr/glibc-compat/lib && \
    mkdir /opt && \
    curl -jksSLH "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" -o /tmp/java.tar.gz \
      http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}u${JAVA_VERSION_MINOR}-b${JAVA_VERSION_BUILD}/${JAVA_PACKAGE}-${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}u${JAVA_VERSION_MINOR}-linux-x64.tar.gz && \
    gunzip /tmp/java.tar.gz && \
    tar -C /opt -xf /tmp/java.tar && \
    ln -s /opt/jdk1.${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}.0_${JAVA_VERSION_MINOR} /opt/jdk && \
    if [ "${JAVA_JCE}" == "unlimited" ]; then echo "Installing Unlimited JCE policy" >&2 && \
      curl -jksSLH "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" -o /tmp/jce_policy-${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}.zip \
        http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jce/${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}/jce_policy-${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}.zip && \
      cd /tmp && unzip /tmp/jce_policy-${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}.zip && \
      cp -v /tmp/UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8/*.jar /opt/jdk/jre/lib/security; \
    fi && \
    sed -i s/#networkaddress.cache.ttl=-1/networkaddress.cache.ttl=30/ $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security && \
    apk del curl glibc-i18n && \
    rm -rf /opt/jdk/*src.zip \
           /opt/jdk/lib/missioncontrol \
           /opt/jdk/lib/visualvm \
           /opt/jdk/lib/*javafx* \
           /opt/jdk/jre/plugin \
           /opt/jdk/jre/bin/javaws \
           /opt/jdk/jre/bin/jjs \
           /opt/jdk/jre/bin/orbd \
           /opt/jdk/jre/bin/pack200 \
           /opt/jdk/jre/bin/policytool \
           /opt/jdk/jre/bin/rmid \
           /opt/jdk/jre/bin/rmiregistry \
           /opt/jdk/jre/bin/servertool \
           /opt/jdk/jre/bin/tnameserv \
           /opt/jdk/jre/bin/unpack200 \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/javaws.jar \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/deploy* \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/desktop \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/*javafx* \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/*jfx* \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libdecora_sse.so \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libprism_*.so \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libfxplugins.so \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libglass.so \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libgstreamer-lite.so \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libjavafx*.so \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libjfx*.so \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/oblique-fonts \
           /opt/jdk/jre/lib/plugin.jar \
           /tmp/* /var/cache/apk/*

# Maven
ENV MAVEN_VERSION 3.3.9
ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/lib/mvn
ENV PATH $MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH

RUN wget http://ftp.fau.de/apache/maven/maven-3/$MAVEN_VERSION/binaries/apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxvf apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz && \
    rm apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz && \
    mv apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION /usr/lib/mvn

# Workspace
ENV WORKSPACE /home/app/

RUN mkdir -p $WORKSPACE
WORKDIR $WORKSPACE

COPY . $WORKSPACE             # Copy Server Project
RUN mvn clean install -DskipTests

ENTRYPOINT mvn exec:java
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '2.1'
services:
  server:
    build: ./server/
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

**server docker logs**:

```
... maven...
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ restful.littleapp ---
Jan 30, 2017 2:10:18 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
INFO: Started listener bound to [0.0.0.0:8080]
Jan 30, 2017 2:10:18 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFO: [HttpServer] Started.
Jersey app started with WADL available at http://0.0.0.0:8080/littleapp/application.wadl
Hit enter to stop it...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.507 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-30T14:10:18+00:00
Jan 30, 2017 2:10:18 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener shutdownNow
INFO: Stopped listener bound to [0.0.0.0:8080]
[INFO] Final Memory: 37M/90M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Normally, the server has to listen...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Maven, but my guess is that `mvn exec:java` launches the server, but forks off? And then the `mvn` command you call exits. In that case, things will shut down because once the initial process exits, everything else in the container also exits. You may need to adjust your `ENTRYPOINT` to run something else, that will keep running and not fork/exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that your main class is waiting for input before stopping the grizzly server. Since the docker container is not run in interactive mode it will never get input on command line and the System.in is terminated. The mvn exec process stops.

You should find a way to keep the grizzly server running without waiting for input.

Something like

```
server.start();
Thread.currentThread().join();  // instead of  System.in.read();
```

**edit**: seems there is a solution like this already described on s.o. [grizzly-http-server-should-keep-running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558079/grizzly-http-server-should-keep-running)  which also incorporates a graceful shutdown by mean of a shutdownhook.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly with the shutdownhook: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558079/grizzly-http-server-should-keep-running#answer-15391081.