# What is the proper way to gracefully shutdown a Grizzly server? (Embedded with Jersey)

Tags: java, server, jersey, shutdown, grizzly

I have the following piece of code to start a basic Embedded Grizzly server running with Jersey.

```
  private static void startServer() {
    ServerResourceConfiguration configuration = new ServerResourceConfiguration();

    HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
            URI.create(BASE_URI),
            configuration,
            false,
            null,
            false);

    server.start();

    if (System.in.read() > -2) {
      server.shutdownNow();
    }
  }
```

This does not look like production level way to stop a server.
What is the best practice to gracefully shut it down ?
I guess a terminal command of some sort. Killing the process would work but it is not very graceful.

I am using Gradle on this project and runs the server with the `gradle run` command.
Could a Gradle task do the job?

Also I have seen this about gracefully terminating a grizzly transport:
http://grizzly-nio.net/2013/08/gracefully-terminating-a-grizzly-transport/
But I am not sure if I would need to use it. I don't understand how to use it.

EDIT: I came across this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15391081/3982755
Is that an acceptable way to terminate an Http server in a production environment?

Comment: httpServer.shutdown() ?

Comment: I mean I want to replace the "hit a key to stop" mechanism. It looks a bit fragile. Isn't there a way to stop it by a terminal command? (other than kill -9)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558079/grizzly-http-server-should-keep-running ?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/apaas/griz-jersey-intro/Grizzly-Jersey-Intro.html ?

Comment: Thanks, I might try the solution with `Ctrl+C` and a shutdown hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no answer so I will post my own, I implemented it with a Shutdown Hook and it works very well.

- The server will wait for all connections to terminate before shutting down.
- To avoid getting blocked for ever if a connection never terminates, we set a grace period(60 seconds)
- After the grace period the server will force termination of all connections

> Here is the code for the hook to be run when the server receives a `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM` signal.

```
public class GrizzlyServerShutdownHookThread extends Thread {

  public static final String THREAD_NAME = "Grizzly Server Shutdown Hook";

  public static final int GRACE_PERIOD = 60;
  public static final TimeUnit GRACE_PERIOD_TIME_UNIT = TimeUnit.SECONDS;

  private final HttpServer server;

  /**
   * @param server The server to shut down
   */
  public GrizzlyServerShutdownHookThread(HttpServer server) {
    this.server = server;
    setName(THREAD_NAME);
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    LOG.info("Running Grizzly Server Shutdown Hook.");
    LOG.info("Shutting down server.");
    GrizzlyFuture<HttpServer> future = server.shutdown(GRACE_PERIOD, GRACE_PERIOD_TIME_UNIT);

    try {
      LOG.info(format("Waiting for server to shut down... Grace period is %s %s", GRACE_PERIOD, GRACE_PERIOD_TIME_UNIT));
      future.get();
    } catch(InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
      LOG.error("Error while shutting down server.", e);
    }

    LOG.info("Server stopped.");
  }
}
```

> Then I register the Hook into the RunTime object this way when I setup the server:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(
    new GrizzlyServerShutdownHookThread(server)
);
```

> And finally, I start the server this way:

```
try {
  server.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
// wait for a SIGINT (Ctrl+c) signal to shut down
try {
  LOG.info("Press CTRL^C to exit..");
  Thread.currentThread().join();
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```